# Implicitly call method on all inherited classes

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, methods

What is the best java programming practice to call a method on all inherited classes. Consider this pseudo code:

```
class TopLevel extends (SecondLevel extends Base)
```

If all these classes have the method 'serializeToString', then how can I call this method throughout the inheritance structure? Te reason for this requirement, is that each class has its own variables it needs to serialize.
Also, there is a further requirement:
Each the class 'TopLevel' and 'SecondLevel' are *not* asbstract, and will need to be the entry point for serializing their entire inheritance.
Eg,

```
SecondLevel.serializeToString()
```

will need to call the method on 'Base' along with itself

And:

```
TopLevel.serializeToString()
```

Would need to call the method on both 'SecondLevel' and 'Base'.

Currently, I have the serializeToString method in base, which then calls a method 'addSerialization' on the entire inheritance (and each implementation must call through to super to propagate the call)
While this works, it seems messy in my code to have two methods working to acheive one (simple?) thing.
What would the best way to acheive this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same overriden method in each class in an inheritance structure callling `super` will give you a chain of calls towards the base class, each one calling the superclass overriden method.

If you don't need to pass extra parameters and the return type is compatible with your logic, you can call `super.serializeToString()` in each class to call the superclass implementation.

```
class TopLevel {
    @Override public String serializeToString() {
        return super.serializeToString() // calls SecondLevel implementation 
                + ", topLevelAttribute: 1";
    }
}

class SecondLevel {
    @Override public String serializeToString() {
        return super.serializeToString() // calls Base implementation 
                + ", secondLevelAttribute: 2";
    }
}

// and so on ...
```

Now, if above solution doesn't fit you logic, you can't avoid creating another method that is called from the superclass.

```
class Base {
    public String serializeToString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        appendSerializedTo(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // can be abstract if there's no implementation here
    protected void appendSerializedTo(StringBuilder sb) {
        sb.append("baseAttribute: 3");
    }
}

class SecondLevel {
    @Override protected void appendSerializedTo(StringBuilder sb) {
        super.appendSerializedTo(sb); // calls Base implementation
        sb.append("secondLevelAttribute: 2");
    }
}

// and so on...
```

Comment: If there are multiple object graphs that all use the same Base class, how does calling the Top Level method cause the method call to be propagated throughout all the object graphs?

Comment: He's asking "how can I call this method throughout the inheritance structure?" You can always go up the inheritance structure using `super`.

Comment: Not exactly: I need to be able to call a method on EVERY class in the inheritance structure, BUT; the method may be called on an intermediate class. Eg, call 'x' on MiddleClass (which is an instance of TopClass). So you see how I need to be able to propagate the call backwards and forwards so to speak. @ericbn understands I think